# How can I build ROP chains on 64 bits if my payload is copied through strcpy?

Tags: rop

It seems 64 bits adresses must end in two null bytes. But strcpy will copy only one null byte in the entire payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. With strcpy() you can put at most one gadget.

The second null byte is often not a problem, as you often find a null byte there anyway from a previous address or integer.

If you need to put a complete ROP chain, you can check if you can trigger the bug repeatedly and fill the buffer in reverse with strings of decreasing length.